# How to publish office Addin Manifest file into Ms Store

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-addins, appsource, powerpoint-web-addins

How to publish a Powerpoint Addin in MS Store?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the process described in the [Make your solutions available in Microsoft AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center) article.

Also see [Am I ready to publish?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/checklist).

Comment: Looks like this answer is no longer accurate.  The documentation at the provided link does not match actual options in the Partner Network site :(